# Jenkins hiding output from aws ecr get-login-password

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy

Hi I trying to prevent aws ecr get-login-password from printing to the Jenkins log. i'm currently doing

```
sh """
aws ecr get-login-password \
    --region <region> \
| skopeo login \
    --username AWS \
    --password-stdin <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com
"""
```

The problem with this is that it prints the output from aws ecr get-login-password into the Jenkins log

log example:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-west-1
+ skopeo login --username us-aws-user --password
```

password is printed here

Comment: Could you please add an example of a log entry to your question? The interesting thing is that the password should be piped directly into docker login, thus not appearing anywhere as visible output.

Comment: @MichiWerner i updated the question, i forgot to edit it showing i use skopeo. I added a log example in the question

Comment: as option use `sh returnStdout:true, script: """....."""`

Comment: or `sh """ your_command > /dev/null """`